# How to suppress range selection for some columns in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

`ag-grid` has a number of properties: `enable*`. Columns have a number of properties: `suppress*`. Setting a `suppress*` for a column has the effect of disabling the effects of some `enable*` property on the grid, for that column.

For example:

- [Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-moving/)
- [Interactive Code Demo on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SZqhVqtRYFJ7GXo41Fxy?p=preview)

```
var columnDefs = [
    {field: 'athlete', suppressMovable: true, width: 150, cellClass: 'suppress-movable-col'},
    {field: 'age', lockPosition: true, cellClass: 'locked-col'},
    {field: 'country', width: 150}
];

var gridOptions = {
    suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns: true,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    defaultColDef: {
        width: 100
    }
};
```

In the above example, the 'athlete' column is not movable due to `suppressMovable:true`. All of the other columns are movable.

I have a grid with `enableRangeSelection: true`

- [Docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-range-selection/)
- [Interactive Code Demo on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/W9yAkD1wBtj71UhPeje5?p=preview)

I would like to prevent the first column from being included in a range selection. 
However, no column property exists called `suppressRangeSelection`.

How can I prevent the user from including the first column in range?

Answer (score 1):

Does not seem like ag-grid allows such behavior, but I managed to do so using Range Selection API:

```
    var gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    rowData: null,
    onRangeSelectionChanged: event => {
        var cellRanges = event.api.getCellRanges();
        if (!cellRanges || cellRanges.length === 0) return;
        var excludeColumn = cellRanges[0].columns.find(
            el => el.getColId() === 'athlete'
        );
        if (!excludeColumn) return;
        var rangeParams = {
            rowStartIndex: cellRanges[0].startRow.rowIndex,
            rowStartPinned: cellRanges[0].startRow.rowPinned,
            rowEndIndex: cellRanges[0].endRow.rowIndex,
            rowEndPinned: cellRanges[0].endRow.rowPinned,
            columns: cellRanges[0].columns
                .map(el => el.getColId())
                .filter(el => el !== 'athlete'),
        };
        event.api.clearRangeSelection();
        event.api.addCellRange(rangeParams);
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a way to apply `enableFillHandle` to a single column without changing the functionality of other columns. This solution works nicely to selectively *enable* specific columns instead of disabling others. Here's an example based on OP's problem.

Hope this helps someone out there!

```
function onRangeSelectionChanged(event) {
    // Must match 'field' property of columns.
    const enabledRangeColumns = new Set(['age', 'country']);
    const [range] = event.api.getCellRanges();

    if (range && !enabledRangeColumns.has(range.startColumn.getColId())) {
        event.api.clearRangeSelection();
    }
}

// ...

const gridOptions = {
    // ...
    enableFillHandle: true,
    enableRangeSelection: true,
    onRangeSelectionChanged
}
```